# Get the 'loose' text of an element with other children in a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I have a component I use like so:

```
<MyAwesomeComponent>
    <a href="/door/left">Left Door</a>
    <a href="/door/Right">Right Door</a>
    Pick a Door
</MyAwesomeComponent>
```

And `MyAwesomeComponent` has this as the render function:

```
render() {
    const { children } = this.props
    return (<Typography>{children}</Typography>)
}
```

If I want to check what the text isI can do this:

```
it('should have some text', () => {
    const component = mount(<MyAwesomeComponent>
        You see Two Doors
        <a href="/door/left">Left Door</a>
        <a href="/door/Right">Right Door</a>
        Pick a Door
    </MyAwesomeComponent>)
    expect(component.children().length).toEqual(3) // fail - it's 2
    expect(component.text()).toEqual('You see Two DoorsPick a Door') // fail it's 'You see Two DoorsLeft DoorRight DoorPick a Door'
});
```

I can accept the last failure, because it considers all the text, but I'm confused as to why the TextNode (e.g. [`Node.TEXT_NODE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) ) is not a child (in the react sense) I can reference?

How do I grab this 'loose' text reference it in a test or the component, maybe like so

```
const textNodes = component.children().filter(child => child.type === 'Text');
expect(textNodes[0]).toEqual('You see Two Doors');
expect(textNodes[1]).toEqual('Pick a Door');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try **shallow** . It works for me.

```
const MyComponent = (
<MyAwesomeComponent>
    <a href="/door/left">Left Door</a>
    <a href="/door/Right">Right Door</a>
    Pick a Door
</MyAwesomeComponent>
);

it('should have some text', () => {
    const component = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    expect(component.children().length).toEqual(3);       
});
```